# How to detect if a dyld-ed symbol exists?

Tags: ios, macos, app-store, dyld

Is there a common way to detect if a symbol exists or not? Like `CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath()` in iOS5, which is only available on iOS5 and later.
If I compile and run apps using this routine on iOS 4 devices, I would get a runtime dyld error.

In Objective-C, +class and other utility APIs can be used to determine the existence of some class or some selector, is there any API to do this on dyld-ed symbols?

Or is it under Apple's permission to use dyld functions for an AppStore oriented app?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To check the availability of a function, explicitly compare its address to NULL or nil.

```
if (CGPathCreateCopyByStrokingPath != NULL) {
    // it exists
}
```

Here's [Apple's documentation on the matter](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html) (listing 3-2).